# spring rest web service official documentation

Tags: spring

Can any one navigate me to official documentation of spring rest web service. I google with multiple keywords but all i got is  [spring rest doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/) which is for web service documentation or spring soap web service doc [soap web service doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/index.html) which is soap web service.

getting started guide of spring rest web service is [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), i need full documentation of this guide.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [official tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) on how to build REST web service with Spring.

For extensive guides on the topic, I suggest you start [here](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series/) and use the [Spring reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/) to gain knowledge on anything unfamiliar in the linked tutorial series.